# How to edit my account section in WooCommerce checkout?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I have customized my WooCommerce checkout in `functions.php` to disable all billing address fields as my Stripe gateway does not require it.

I would like to allow customers to create an account during checkout too but it only asks for a username/password and wordpress accounts require an email. since I have disabled email in billing section the user cannot register.

I do not want the email address to stay in billing details as it will always show.

My ideal solution is having it in the account section.

How do I either

1. move the email address from billing to the create an account section
2. create an email address field for the account section?

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> You can use `woocommerce_checkout_fields` hook
>
> https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.1.0/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L265
>
> - Get an array of checkout fields.

---

Add the following code to `functions.php`

```php
// Add field
function filter_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $fields ) {    
    $fields['account']['billing_email'] = array(
        'label'        => __('E-mailadres', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'     => true,
        'type'         => 'email',
        'class'        => array('form-row-wide'),
        'validate'     => array('email'),
        'autocomplete' => 'email'
    );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'filter_woocommerce_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );
```